Case insensitive version of strstr()
In order to solve a problem from K&R C book, I am trying to write a function strstrci() which  is the case insensitive version of strstr()
char * strstrci (char *s, char *p)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; *(s + i) != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (*(s + i) == *p || *(s + i) == *p + 32 || *(s + i) == *p - 32)
        {
            for (j = 1; *(s + i + j) == *(p + j) || *(s + i + j) == *(p + j) + 32 || *(s + i + j) == *(p + j) - 32; j++)
            {
                if (*(p + j) == '\0')
                    return (s + i);
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

The function seems to work well for all cases except when the pattern is the last part of the input string. For example:
string : On a wall he sat
pattern: sat
In such a case it returns a NULL.
Please point out the mistake

First thing before you do anything else: get rid of the evil *(s + i) syntax. It is 100% equivalent to  s[i] and therefore achieves nothing but making the code much harder to read.

I assume you have tried to debug the code? Like using a debugger to step through the code line by line, while monitoring variables and their values, to see what happens? Using pen and paper to help visualize arrays, pointers and other variables is usually a great help.

@DmitrySazonov If it is not a site for asking about specific technical problems then what is the site for? The main problem here is that the OP is learning from K&R so they will not pick up best practices, let alone how to use a debugger.

On a couple of different notes, beside using proper array indexing as mentioned above I also recommend you use tolower or toupper for lower-/upper-case conversions. And you check for p[j] == '\0' too late, after you possibly go beyond the terminator.

The problem is not reproducible as stated: It returns a null pointer when the pattern is not at the end of the string being searched and returns a correct pointer into the string when the pattern is at the end, which is the reverse of what is stated in the question (also neglecting the flaws in the case-insensitive comparison that have some false positives).

if (*(s + i) == *p || *(s + i) == *p + 32 || *(s + i) == *p - 32) is totally wrong (what happens if one is a space and the other is a null terminator?) Never ever use magic numbers like 32.

There are multiple problems:

The arguments should be typed const char *.
Empty strings should be handled in a way consistent with strstr: an empty string pointed to by p should be found at the beginning of s, even if s points to an empty string.
The offset 32 is ASCII specific, which may be OK, but it is not correct for all characters. Your function will erroneously match @, [, \, ] with respectively `, {, |, } and ^, among other pairs that you indiscriminately consider equivalent.
The index variables i and j should have type size_t to allow for arbitrary long strings.
The inner loop only tests for *(p + j) == '\0' if the characters match, hence the function only matches the needle at the end of the haystack string.
Using the pointer syntax *(p + j) == '\0' is cumbersome and less readable than the equivalent array syntax p[j] == '\0'.

Here is a modified version using the standard header <ctype.h>:
#include <ctype.h>

char *strstrci(const char *s, const char *p) {
    if (*p == '\0')
        return (char *)s;
    for (; *s; s++) {
        if (tolower((unsigned char)*s) == tolower((unsigned char)*p)) {
            size_t i;
            for (i = 1;; i++) {
                if (p[i] == '\0')
                    return (char *)s;
                if (tolower((unsigned char)s[i]) != tolower((unsigned char)p[i]))
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}


Thank you so much chqrlie for the solution.

It is very hard to read your function.

Use indexes instead of pointer arithmetic. It is the same but it is much easier for humans.
Use standard functions to change case.
Use size_t for indexes and sizes.
Try to be const correct.
Use meaningful variable names.

Generally, it was easier for me to write it instead of analyzing:
char *stristr(const char *haystack, const char *needle)
{
    char *result = NULL;

    if (haystack && needle) // Ensure neither input is NULL
    {
        if (*needle == '\0') // If the needle is empty
        {
            result = (char *)haystack;
        }
        else
        {
            const char *h = haystack;

            while (*h) 
            {
                const char *h_sub = h;
                const char *n_sub = needle;

                while (*n_sub && *h_sub && tolower((unsigned char)*h_sub) == tolower((unsigned char)*n_sub))
                {
                    ++h_sub;
                    ++n_sub;
                }

                if (*n_sub == '\0')
                {
                    result = (char *)h;
                    break;
                }

                ++h; 
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}


or using indexes:
char *strstrci(const char *haystack, const char *needle)
{
    if (*needle == '\0') // If the needle is empty
    {
        return (char *)haystack; 
    }

    for (; *haystack; haystack++) 
    {
        if (tolower((unsigned char)*haystack) == tolower((unsigned char)*needle))
        {
            size_t needleIndex = 1; 

            while (needle[needleIndex] != '\0' && haystack[needleIndex] != '\0' &&
                   tolower((unsigned char)haystack[needleIndex]) == tolower((unsigned char)needle[needleIndex]))
            {
                needleIndex++;
            }

            if (needle[needleIndex] == '\0')
            {
                return (char *)haystack;
            }
        }
    }

    return NULL; // No match found
}

Tests:
void runTests()
{
    char *result;

    
    result = stristr("On a wall he sat", "sat");
    assert(result != NULL && strcmp(result, "sat") == 0);

    result = stristr("Hello, World!", "world");
    assert(result != NULL && strcmp(result, "World!") == 0);

    result = stristr("Programming is fun", "fun");
    assert(result != NULL && strcmp(result, "fun") == 0);

    result = stristr("Some text", "");
    assert(result == "Some text");

    result = stristr("", "anything");
    assert(result == NULL);

    result = stristr("", "");
    assert(result != NULL && strcmp(result, "") == 0);

    result = stristr("Case insensitive search", "missing");
    assert(result == NULL);

    result = stristr("CaseInsensitive", "caseinsensitive");
    assert(result != NULL && strcmp(result, "CaseInsensitive") == 0);

    result = stristr("CaseInsensitive Search", "INSENSITIVE");
    assert(result != NULL && strcmp(result, "Insensitive Search") == 0);

    result = stristr("Short", "This is a long needle");
    assert(result == NULL);

    result = stristr("A@B#C!D$E%", "@b#c");
    assert(result != NULL && strcmp(result, "@B#C!D$E%") == 0);

    printf("All tests passed!\n");
}

int main()
{
    runTests();
    return 0;
}

https://godbolt.org/z/cb63Y8vW9

You fixed the parameter types to be pointers to const, why not the return type?

@n.m.couldbeanAI For the same reason strstr does not return const

Thanks @0___________ for the elegant solution and also many thanks for the elaborate test lisst you provided. I could finally come up with a function that passed all the tests.  However, I still cannot think of a way of changing an alphabet from uppercase to powercase and viceversa without using the number "32".

@VinayakDeshmukh see my code.

Certainly @0___________. Thanks again.
